# Getting a taxonomy term for the current post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to populate a form value field with a taxonomy term associated with the current post,

I must have tried 20 things but cant find the right solution .?

I have meta fields but that's easy I have just used this:

```
$ref = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'job_ref', true );
```

and this for the form field:

```
  <input type="text" class="text" name="job_ref" id="job_ref" value="
  <?php echo $ref; ?>" />
```

So I'm looking for a similar solution for a taxonomy term ..?

Many thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `wp_get_post_terms` to retrieve your post terms. syntax  here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Comment: Many thanks for your help... you have confirmed the solution i was going to use...

Comment: can you please give us an example of implementing this inside loop of single-CPT.php?

Comment: There are examples on the page linked

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. It would be great to see examples in this answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/). 
The difference between [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) and [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) is that `get_the_terms()`'s results are cached.