# Wordpress How to get current taxonomy term?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

On a page of single custom type post, I'm trying to get current taxonomy term

```
$current_term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
print_r($current_term);
```

current_term, get_query_var('term') and get_query_var('taxonomy') return nothing

UPDATE:

$term = get_queried_object(); print_r($term) ; :

```
    WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] =&gt; 324
    [post_author] =&gt; 1
    [post_date] =&gt; 2019-10-17 14:18:37
    [post_date_gmt] =&gt; 2019-10-17 14:18:37
    [post_content] =&gt; The performance data 
    [post_title] =&gt; Diversified Fund
    [post_excerpt] =&gt; 
    [post_status] =&gt; publish
    [comment_status] =&gt; closed
    [ping_status] =&gt; closed
    [post_password] =&gt; 
    [post_name] =&gt; diversified-value-fund
    [to_ping] =&gt; 
    [pinged] =&gt; 
    [post_modified] =&gt; 2019-10-31 20:44:43
    [post_modified_gmt] =&gt; 2019-10-31 20:44:43
    [post_content_filtered] =&gt; 
    [post_parent] =&gt; 0
    [guid] =&gt; http://hwcm.my/?post_type=funds&amp;p=324
    [menu_order] =&gt; 1
    [post_type] =&gt; funds
    [post_mime_type] =&gt; 
    [comment_count] =&gt; 0
    [filter] =&gt; raw
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a taxonomy term for the current post in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767120/getting-a-taxonomy-term-for-the-current-post-in-wordpress)

Comment: `wp_get_post_terms` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Answer (score 0):

have found the solution:

```
print_r(get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'fund_category'));
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] =&gt; 5
            [name] =&gt; US Equity
            [slug] =&gt; us-equity
            [term_group] =&gt; 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] =&gt; 5
            [taxonomy] =&gt; fund_category
            [description] =&gt; 
            [parent] =&gt; 0
            [count] =&gt; 6
            [filter] =&gt; raw
            [term_order] =&gt; 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use queried object

```
$term = get_queried_object();
print_r($term);
```

Comment: Updated the question with output

Comment: $taxonomy_slug = "your-taxonomy";
$terms = get_the_terms( $term->ID, $taxonomy_slug );
if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $out[] = '<a href="'. get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy_slug ) .'">'. $term->name
. "</a>\n";
  }
  echo implode(', ', $out );
}

Comment: If you still getting issues. I can help you. you can join me on skype. Logicdigger@gmail.com